# How can I check if a list contains the same element repeated in a row?

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to define a function that recognizes when a list has two elements that get repeated right after one another, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Could you share with us what you've tried so far, and any ideas you might have?

Comment: Are you downvoting all the (correct) answers on your own question as soon as they appear, or is that someone else (maybe punishing them before you're a help vampire and they're enabling you)?

Answer (score 3):

You could just iterate through the list's items and compare adjacent elements:

```
def dups_in_row(l):
    for i in range (len(l) - 1):
        if l[i] == l[i + 1]:
            return True;
    return False;
```

Comment: This should work, I'm not sure why these answers are being downvoted.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `zip` to iterate over the list, and the same list offset by one:

```
  def f(l):    
    for a,b in zip(l, l[1:]):
        if a == b:
           return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def checker(thelist):
    for num,element in enumerate(thelist):
        if (num+1)<len(thelist) and thelist[num] == thelist[num+1]:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: What's wrong with it?